# How can I apply scrollbars to each individual part of a Canvas split into parts?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a website set up so that one Javascript file calls three others and sets them up as parts of a Canvas. Is there any way to set up scroll bars to scroll through each part individually? I have been looking at HTML for this but I can't figure out how to get it to apply to only one part because the main function sets up all the parts, and because this is a type of game and needs to draw things and update them, I can't separate the code.

Comment: Either put into three canvases, or implement your own scrollbar from scratch, or give up on separate scrollbars.

Comment: Create a single in-memory canvas containing your complete contents for all three subsections. Then create 3 onscreen oversized canvases each wrapped in a smaller container div with `overflow:scroll`. Use the clipping version of `drawImage` to split the contents of the in-memory container into each of the 3 on-screen canvases.

Answer (score 0):

Set heights to the containers and apply CSS

```
.container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: You should add that OP needs to split the drawings in 3 different canvases first